# Can I force mapstruct to delegate a mapping method to another mapping method or a default (builtin) conversion?

Tags: mapstruct

Can I force mapstruct to delegate a mapping method to another mapping method or a default (builtin) conversion?

I basically would like to access a custom mapping method of a `uses` MapperA inside the custom mapping method of the using MapperX. But I can't get a hold of the injected MapperA inside the custom mapping method of MapperX.

The same is true for builtin conversions. I want to make use of a builtin conversion of mapstruct inside a custom method. Like convert from Date to ZonedDateTime.

e.g.:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="cdi")
public interface MapperA {
    A fromB(B b);
    
    default Q fromR(R r) {
        Q q = ..<do some stuff with r>..
        return q;
    }
}

@Mapper(componentModel="cdi"
    uses = MapperA.class
)
public interface MapperX {
    default X custom(Y y) {
        Date someJavaUtilDate = customDateFromY(y);
        //I dont want to code Date->ZonedDateTime myself
        //I want mapstruct to do its builtin conversion, so call placeholder:
        X.myZonedDateTime = builtinConversionPlaceholder(someJavaUtilDate)
        
        R r = ..<do some stuff with y>..
        X.q = usesMapperPlaceholder(r); // injected "uses MapperA" is not directly accessible here?
    }
    
    @org.mapstruct.Find_Me_A_Matching_Method_Builtin_Or_In_Uses_Mapper
    // will not map properties of Date to ZonedDateTime
    // but will use mapstruct builtin conversion code
    ZonedDateTime builtinConversionPlaceholder(java.util.Date date);
    
    @org.mapstruct.Find_Me_A_Matching_Method_Builtin_Or_In_Uses_Mapper
    // will delegate to MapperA.fromR
    Q usesMapperPlaceholder(R r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to force MapStruct to use. build in conversion method.

What you can do is to create some wrapper objects that will be mapped between `java.util.Date` and `ZonedDateTime`, MapStruct will then map those using the built in mappings.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel="cdi")
public interface MapperA {
    A fromB(B b);
    
    default Q fromR(R r) {
        Q q = ..<do some stuff with r>..
        return q;
    }
}

@Mapper(componentModel="cdi"
    uses = MapperA.class
)
public abstract class MapperX {

    @Inject
    MapperA mapperA;

    default X custom(Y y) {
        Date someJavaUtilDate = customDateFromY(y);
        X.myZonedDateTime = toZonedDateTime(someJavaUtilDate).getValue();
        
        R r = ..<do some stuff with y>..
        X.q = mapperA.fromR(r);
    }
    
    Wrapper<ZonedDateTime> toZonedDateTime(Wrapper<java.util.Date> date);
    
    static class Wrapper<T> {
        private T value;

        //getters and setters
        
    }
}
```